# Is it possible to map private members and methods to be public with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

lets say I have

```
class MyClass {
    private A = 5;

    public printA() {
        console.log(`A is ${this.A}`)
        this.updateA();
    }

    private updateA() {
        this.A = Math.random();
    }
}
```

is it possible to map it to convert all the private to public? like

```
const myClassWithAllPublic = <somethingHere>new MyClass();
```

My use case is the follow:

I have a big service with a lot of public APIs. I want to construct debug functions that change the state of the class so I can say something like "Put A in value 7". For that I want to send `myClassWithAllPublic` where I can modify it without creating noise in my service class.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can do that without much ado by simply setting `myObject['privateProp']=whatever`.

Comment: Yes but it isn't typesafe. And in our project access via `['something']` is forbidden (ts-lint)

Comment: `keyof` and mapped types don't work with `private`. what about something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1vQA4CcBLANzABcBTaAQWgF5oBWAbixwJPKoCF7oAiAGYB7YfwwBfDBgD0M6BQC2hMjAr58w-NEKDoAawrxoW6KRABXKmXi4qFgHb6HwgO4OMwYQ4hkaALjgkFAgAbX5qfgBdPgBmT29faG5AhGRIMP5uaL5+ACMwfHEMQUdgMkJvaAgKMgAFIlJKAB4AFQUAD0oHABMYYTyAKwpygD4ACjJA1oAaaEUwXEC0aFCAaUDfIgcAcyjAsAdjCQBKafQ2bHxai3wHaAB5IZGyADoMwh2HSbmF3BPJNIvD4-MI+A4KK4gukoOMATV6o0uONhHMVtQ5rxTkDEsIQBRXiBhDsUQCgA) to at least check the prop key and value types ?